# primary and secondary objectives

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Suppose an activity has two objectives (primary and one secondary objective). In this case, which objective does *cmi.objectives.0.xxx* refer to? primary or secondary?

Answer (score 4):

Secondary objective. Consider the following example:

```
<imsss:objectives>
<imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="primary_1" />
<imsss:objective objectiveID="obj_1" />
<imsss:objective objectiveID="obj_2" />
<imsss:objective objectiveID="obj_3" />
</imsss:objectives>
```

All objectives that have the tag `<imsss:objecive>` can be accessed by using "cmi.objecives.n.XX".
In this example we have only three objectives which can be accessed using "cmi.objectives.n.xx".
However, the primary objecive will not be directly accessed by the SCO. If you want to access the success status of the primary objective for example, you have to use "cmi.success_status". Think of the primary objective as the SCO itself. For instance, "objective satisfied status" refers to the primary objective.